# How to keep track of if a user has already seen a post or not?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I am building a social media type application using MERN stack. When a user sees a list of posts in my application, I want to highlight the new posts that the user has never seen differently. How may I do so?
I think I need to find a way such that the node server knows if the user has already fetched a particular post or not. What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I would choose graph type database for this as you can create a relationship between the post and user. Durning query, you can get a relationship with the post. I suggest creating an endpoint that checks if the user interacts with the post. You can have any interactions with the post. As for detection, use the front end to detect and send requests. The next problem is when the post is considered seen.